Symplectic approximation to a given matrix
I am interested in understanding methods to rigorously compute the closest symplectic matrix approximation to an arbitrary matrix $A$. A symplectic matrix $S$ satisfies the condition $ S^T J S = J $, where $$ J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ -I & 0 \end{bmatrix} ,$$ and $ I $ denotes the identity matrix.
Specifically, given a matrix $ A $, how can one find a symplectic matrix $S$ that minimizes a measure of distance to $ A $, such as the Frobenius norm or operator norm?
Furthermore, if we know that there exists a symplectic matrix $ S $ such that $\|A - S\| \leq \epsilon$ for some matrix norm $ \|\cdot\| $ and $ \epsilon > 0 $, how can one find a matrix $B$ such that $ \|A - B\| \leq f(\epsilon) $, where $ f(\epsilon) $ is a function determining the closeness of $ B $ to $ A $ based on $ \epsilon $?
I would appreciate any insights and references to relevant literature that address these questions. (I am aware of the fact that for the analogous problem, where orthogonal or unitary matrices are considered instead of symplectic matrices, an analytical solution can be found.)

Try setting up a simple optimization problem
$$
\def\frob#1{\Big| #1 \Big|_F^2}
\min_B; \frob{B^TJB-J} ;+; \lambda\frob{B-A} \
$$
where the first term captures the symplectic constraint and the second (for some fixed $\lambda$-value)  keeps the solution close to $A.;$

Thanks, but I'd like rigorous guarantees.

If $A$ is almost symplectic, you can use Cayley Transforms to make it fully symplectic
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\cay#1{\op{cay}\LR{#1}}
&\sym M = \tfrac12\LR{M+M^T}, \qquad \cay M = \LR{M+I}^{-1}\LR{M-I} \
&S ,=, \cay{J\sym{J^T\cay A}} \
}$$

Do you have any references? In particular, I would be interested in the "approximation" error.

Dennis S Bernstein's Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas is chock full of esoteric formulas like this.  Check the index for Hamiltonian matrices and Symplectic matrices.
